# What does this sentence mean in this context here?

Tags: grammar

Yet it may be the very familiarity of such images—no one of which has particular ascension over another—that shifts the emphasis, in “Memory of the Camps,” to two sequences. [Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/movies/2014/01/hitchcock-and-the-holocaust.html)

Comment: Please edit your question to pinpoint the specific part of the sentence you don't understand, so that we can get a better idea of what exactly is confusing you. Once you have done so, feel free to flag this question for reopening!

Answer (score 1):

My gloss:

We've seen images like these (those described in the previous paragraph) many times, and none of them stands out from the rest in our memory. This makes it so more of our attention falls to two series of shots (described in the remainder of the paragraph) when watching “Memory of the Camps”.